# For-loop counter and variable assignment in Django template?

Tags: django

I'm trying to obtain the equivalent in Django's template language. Is this possible?
I want to print the final number , not the count each iteration.

```
int num=0;
for (int i = 0; i < numitems; i++)
{
   num += 1;
}
```

I've tried:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
   {{ forloop.counter0 }}
   {counter}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {{ tasks | length }} is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: ryan, please use answer box to post the answer. As a nice bonus, you can accept your own answer :)

Comment: I did that in the hopes that the previous person who deleted their comment would re-comment their answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it because i thought I might have been making too many assumptions on what you were looking for. Glad you saw it in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
{{ tasks | length }}
```